# SQL Server No Matching Keys Error Messages

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to execute a database script I created through the Forward Engineer Addin for Microsoft Visio.

The following are the errors I am receiving and the section of the code the error message is referencing:

Error 1:

```
Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.Account_BillingAccount' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'Account_BillingAccount_InvoiceDetail_FK1'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 12
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Code Reference 1:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceDetail] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [Account_BillingAccount_InvoiceDetail_FK1] FOREIGN KEY (
[BillingAccountNumber]
, [AccountNumber]
)
REFERENCES [dbo].[Account_BillingAccount] (
[BillingAccountNumber]
, [AccountNumber]
)
```

Error 2:

```
Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.ManagerContract' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'ManagerContract_RegionalCoordinators_FK1'.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

Code Reference 2:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RegionalCoordinators] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [ManagerContract_RegionalCoordinators_FK1] FOREIGN KEY (
[AssociateID]
, [WritingNumber]
)
REFERENCES [dbo].[ManagerContract] (
[AssociateID]
, [WritingNumber]
)
```

What is the most effective way to remove the aforementioned errors?

Comment: You got to have a primary key or unique key in the referenced tables that matches the column list. So in `ManagerContract` you need a unique key on `AssociateID, WritingNumber` and in `Account_BillingAccount` you need it on `BillingAccountNumber, AccountNumber`.

Comment: What is the syntax to add this unique key?

Answer (score 0):

You got to have a primary key or unique key in the referenced tables that matches the column list. So in `ManagerContract` you need a unique key on `AssociateID, WritingNumber` and in `Account_BillingAccount` you need it on `BillingAccountNumber, AccountNumber`

Have a look here about how to create unique constraints. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx

> ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] ADD CONSTRAINT
>   UNQ_*TableName*_ColumnName UNIQUE ([ColumnName])

Something like this in your case.

```
alter table dbo.ManagerContract 
 add constraint UNQ_ManagerContract_AssociateID_WritingNumber 
 unique (AssociateID, WritingNumber)
```

Comment: I already have AssociateID and WritingNumber as the primary keys of ManagerContract. Do I still need to include them as unique keys?

Comment: @idealistikz - No, that should be enough. Are you sure that they are in there when your SQL-script tries to add the FK?. Perhaps you have an issue in your script with dependencies and order of executing statements?

Comment: AssociateID and WritingNumber are set as primary keys before the ALTER TABLE statement. What could be the issue?

Comment: @idealistikz - Don't know. Can you update your question with the DDL for the table ManagerContract (`create table ...`) including the definition of primary keys etc?